# Cordova 3.3 getting after fresh clone from git

Tags: xcode, cordova, github

i have cloned my project from the git.before that it was working fine now when i am running the project in Xcode then  getting error:
`Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh: line 2: cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh: Permission denied`, how to solve that issue .i  am using mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give full permission to that folder
open terminal
go to the parent folder
then type 
 `sudo chmnod -R 777 folder_name`

OR 
try

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova/lib
sudo chmod +x copy-www-build-step.sh
```

OR

```
 cd platforms/ios/cordova/lib
 sudo chmod 777 copy-www-build-step.sh
```

Comment: how to give permission